# How do I rename Electron in the "Opens with" file association context menu on Windows?

Tags: windows, electron

I have renamed the binary and used rcedit to set both ProductName and InternalName but the "Opens with" context menu has remained as Electron.

[image: Example of the menu]

Is it possible to rename this reference without building Electron?

Comment: How are you building the executable for windows?

Comment: @förschter I'm not building the executable, just using the release from git and following their rebranding steps found here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/application-distribution#rebranding-with-downloaded-binaries

Comment: Oh, that doesn't work. I think instead of building electron you could also use one of the packagers from electron-builder or electron-forge.

Answer (score 0):

After forgetting about this question and after a bit of research I found that upon launching any program for the first time Windows will set a registry property "FriendlyAppName" and never update it again.

Manually modifying this on my system resolved these context menu names, however I'm unsure if the modified binary will retain the desired FriendlyAppName on systems that have never run the application before.